# Can you use arcpy.da.SearchCursor() to go through multiple feature classes or shapefiles?

Tags: arcpy

I have three shapefiles that I need to perform a function on. Can I nest SearchCursors or is there a way to run an arcpy.SearchCursor through a list of feature classes/shapefiles?
something like below. I am trying not to have 100 lines of code. The files share field names so "fieldone" exists in all three shapefiles.

```
with arcpy.SearchCursor(featureclassList,("fieldone","fieldtwo") as cursor:
    for x in cursor:
      print(x[0])
or
with arcpy.SearchCursor(shapefile1,shapefile2,("fieldone","fieldtwo") as cursor:
    for x in cursor:
       (perform math expression)
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the result of your function?

Answer (score 10):

No. The cursor only accepts 1 feature class.

Using your example, just wrap the cursor in the loop and pass in the feature class one at a time.

```
for fc in featureclassList:
    with arcpy.SearchCursor(fc,("fieldone","fieldtwo") as cursor:
        for x in cursor:
            print(x[0])
```